# Ios - filter the asset group

Tags: ios, filter, assets, enumerate

I would like to get some photos from the Asset Library using the url of the asset as filter parameter:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
    usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if (nil != group) {
            // be sure to filter the group so you only get photos
            [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:
            ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
                if (nil != result) {
                    ALAssetRepresentation *repr = [result defaultRepresentation];
                    BOOL exists = [...[repr.url absoluteString]];
....
```

The problem is that the enumerateAssetsUsingBlock block get all the photos one by one and that process is too slow. Is there any other way to filter the asset group?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found solution??